# Double click in any listbox in windows applications

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mouse, windows-7-embedded

I am facing a weird issue while double click in windows 7 embedded OS.

Consider a listbox having several items and offers a double click functionality to open an item to show more details in separate window.

Here while performing the double click, one click was made on one item and another click on another item, finally the details window had opened for the second item.

the click is in normal speed only.

This is occurring in any application which has lists like "ListBox, ListView DataGrid".. any thing.

Is this a problem of Mouse, OS, WPF, winforms, C#, graphic driver ?

Please help.

Comment: Please share your code. Also do you have any listbox click event apart from doubleclick ?

Comment: Code ??? this is occurring in all the applications on windows embedded OS. even c++, normal windows forms , WPF etc., What could be the problem ?